# Different behavior in shell script vs in shell?

Tags: shell-script, darwin

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the `grep $1` part to `grep '$1'` (while I was trying to mean `grep "$1"`) in the script and this time I got the

`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`

message (instead of the `Terminated: 15` message). I don't understand what's going on.

**QUESTION:**

I have written a simple shell script named `mykill`.

`mykill`:

```
#!/bin/sh

kill `ps -A | grep $1 | grep -v 'grep' | grep -Eom 1 '^[0-9]+'`
```

However, there is a weird behavior. When I write the line:

```
kill `ps -A | grep process_name | grep -v 'grep' | grep -Eom 1 '^[0-9]+'`
```

manually on bash, if nothing comes up as the output of `ps -A | grep process_name`, I get the following:

`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`

If something comes up, the command executes correctly and terminates silently.

Now, if I run the script by executing the `mykill` file, if something comes up as the output of `ps -A | grep process_name`, the script executes correctly and terminates silently, which is the same behavior as executing the command manually.

But if nothing comes up as the output of `ps -A | grep process_name`, I don't get the message about the usage of the kill command. Instead, I get:

```
Terminated: 15
```

I have also checked out the return codes. After I try to terminate a non existent process by manually writing the command on the shell, `echo $?` gives `1`. However, after I try to terminate a non existent process by calling the script, `echo $?` gives `143`.

What's going on here? Why am I observing different behaviors when executing the same command by manually writing it on the shell, vs executing it within a shell script?

NOTE: Both `sh` and my working shell are `bash`.

BONUS: Could my shell script be written in a more efficient and/or elegant way, using only [POSIX utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/utilities.html)? If so, how?

Comment: You can write your script more efficiently by using `pkill`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Updated the BONUS part to allow only POSIX utilities.

Comment: You're on some BSD system, right?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, I'm on Darwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A portability note. The output format for `ps -A` is [unspecified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html#tag_20_96_10) for non Unix-conformant systems (like FreeBSD) (you'll notice that the output format sections and the description of the `-f` option are all tagged *XSI* in the specification), so you can't really post-process it reliably portably.

For instance, with the `ps` from `procps` on Linux, it will output, `PID TTY          TIME CMD` columns (where `CMD` is the process name, not command args) while on FreeBSD it outputs `PID TT  STAT    TIME COMMAND` (with `COMMAND` being the args).

Given your usage of `grep -v grep`, I suppose you're expecting the latter or at least that `ps -A` outputs the arguments of the command that the process executed as opposed to just the process name (usually derived from the file name of the last execute command or the first (0<sup>th</sup>) argument).

If your `grep` is intended to `grep` on the command arguments only, you should use:

```
ps -A -o pid= -o args=
```

whose output is specified by POSIX.

Now, your problem is that `mykill` is killing itself because the `mykill foo` matches `foo`.

Another problem is that `mykill grep` would not kill anything.

Here, you could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
PATTERN=${1?} export PATTERN
trap '' TERM # ignore SIGTERM for the shell and its children
ps -A -o pid= -o args= | awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["PATTERN"] {
  system("kill " $1); exit}'
```

(note that POSIX doesn't specify the path of the POSIX `sh` utility nor the she-bang mechanism, so `/bin/sh` may not be a POSIX shell. In practice though, she-bang is supported on most POSIX systems and `/bin/sh` is either a POSIX `sh` or the Bourne `sh` and the above code should work in both).

Though that's not ideal as it always return a true (0) exit status even when no process is found. A better approach would be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
pattern=${1?}
trap '' TERM # ignore SIGTERM for the shell and its children
ps -A -o pid= -o args= | grep -e "$pattern" | {
  read pid args && kill "$pid"
}
```

In both cases, we only kill the first matching process as your `grep -m 1` approach suggests you want to do.

Now, with `trap '' SIGTERM` we make sure our processes are not killed which would be OK if we were to kill **all** the matching processes but since here, we're only killing the first matching one, the problem is that that first one may very well be the one running `mykill pattern` or `grep pattern`.

Rather than adding some `grep -ve grep -e mykill` (which would not be foolproof as it could exclude more processes than intended), you could try and compare the process IDs of the matched processes.

```
#! /bin/sh -
pattern=${1?}
trap '' TERM # ignore SIGTERM for the shell and its children
             # just in case
psoutput=$(exec ps -A -o pid= -o ppid= -o args=)
printf '%s\n' "$psoutput" | grep -e "$pattern" | {
  while read -r pid ppid args; do
    if [ "$pid" -ne "$$" ] && [ "$ppid" -ne "$$" ]; then
      kill "$pid"
      exit # with the exit status of kill above
    fi
  done
  exit 1 # not found
}
```

(note that `$(...)` and `read -r` are POSIX but not Bourne).

Or using `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh` or `yash` (none of which are POSIX commands), that  is a shell with builtin regular expression matching:

```
#! /bin/bash -
pattern=${1?}
trap '' TERM # ignore SIGTERM for the shell and its children
             # just in case
psoutput=$(exec ps -A -o pid= -o ppid= -o args=)
printf '%s\n' "$psoutput" | {
  while read -r pid ppid args; do
    if ((pid != $$ && ppid != $$)) && [[ $args =~ $pattern ]]; then
      kill "$pid"
      exit # with the exit status of kill above
    fi
  done
  exit 1 # not found
}
```

Comment: Regarding the output of `ps -A`, actually I am getting the former version (`PID TTY          TIME CMD`). I couldn't understand why using `grep -v grep` would suggest the other output format.

Comment: @Utku, `grep -v grep` would be to filter out the `grep foo` line (that `grep foo` being started by `mykill foo`) that would match `foo`. But if the `CMD` field only contains the process name (so only `grep`, not `grep foo`), then that wouldn't make sense. Does the `CMD` column contain the process name or the command arguments on your system?

Comment: Oh, yes of course. But my `CMD` column includes _both_ process name and command arguments. That is, it includes the full command line that is used to start the process.

Comment: @Utku, yes, that's the point. See my edited answer where I hope it's clearer.

Comment: By the way, what does `${1?}` mean? I have read the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) part of the bash manual but couldn't understand.

Comment: @Utku, it exits the script with an error if `$1` is not set. You can also specify the error message like `${1?need a pattern}`. In the bash manual, pay attention to the _Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset_ sentence.